# How does SQL truncate data when inserting?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, truncation

I am working on an SSIS package that does many things, one of which is to copy data from a table on one database to a table on a different database. On one of my package components, I am getting truncation warnings, because the source table has `ColumnA NCHAR(10)` while the destination table has `ColumnA NCHAR(1)`. ColumnA in the source table only ever has values that are 1 character long, so theoretically, I can ignore the truncation warnings that I am receiving, since the source data is only 1 character long anyway.

Am I correct that I can ignore these warnings? How exactly does SQL truncate data in these instances? If there is only one character in the source column that holds 10 characters, will that one character always be copied to the destination or is there a chance that even that single character will not be copied over?

Comment: If you 100% sure it's always going to be "1" and if no one else ever going to work with this "solution" - then yes, you can ignore the warning

Comment: It will always bring over the first character in the 10 character string. So if you have leading spaces you will get a space in the destination.

Comment: Remember that SQL Server uses UTF-16 encoding so an nchar(1) can't always contain a single character. Thanks to Unicode fun with with surrogate characters, and the Supplementary Multilingual Plane (containing emoji and such) and Supplementary Ideographic Plane, some code points are expressed using multiple pairs of bytes.

Answer (score 0):

SSIS always trims the last characters. So if you're handling a 9 character string like '123456789' and inserting it into a column with a column with 5 characters SSIS would trim the last 4 characters off,transforming the string to be '12345'. If you were inserting into a column with length of 1 character SSIS would trim down to '1'.

If you are confident that you will never receive a string that is longer than 1 character from a source that could potentially hold ten characters feel free to ignore the warning. This is, of course, in theory. In practice you would be far better off writing a SELECT statement or similar for your OLE DB source such as:

```
CASE WHEN LEN(ColumnA) <> 1
THEN 'e' --e for error; destination column length is 1
ELSE ColumnA
END AS ColumnA
```

to handle such an error.

If you have an API source or other non-OLE DB source you can use SSIS' derived column for a similar effect.

Comment: Insert and retrieve handles truncation in different ways. Insert should raise an error.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean when you say "retrieve". If you want, you could extend the length of THEN 'e' to a string 'error' with a length of 5. Loading into a column of 1 kills the SSIS task which could be a potential solution depending on E. Kelly's  design requirements

Comment: INSERT data vs. SELECT data.